# Excel VBA Procedure Error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a peculiar issue with a VBA assignment for school.  The issue I'm having is VBA is giving me a compile error when Excel tries running the code at start up on a specific Workbook.  It keeps telling me that the code cannot be run outside a procedure, but I don't know why it's telling me that when it needs to run at the start of the document.  Here's my almost final code that's throwing the error...

```
Option Explicit
Worksheets("StartPage").Activate
Worksheets("Payroll").Protected
cmdDisplay.Enabled = False
cmdEmpData.Enabled = False
cmdEmployees.Enabled = True
cmdReset.Enabled = True
Public intNumEmp As Integer
```

That code runs BEFORE the first subroutine is run, which, aside from the variable, is throwing the error.  Should I put an access modifier before them to fix the issue, or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: You can declare variables outside of a procedure, but you cannot execute functions, change properties, or assign values to variables. Except for your declaration of intNumEmp, try putting the rest of your stuff into a workbook open procedure.

Answer (score 2):

@RonRosenfeld is correct, here is what the code would look like inside of the ThisWorkbook module:

```
Option Explicit
Public intNumEmp As Integer

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("StartPage").Activate
    Worksheets("Payroll").Protected
    cmdDisplay.Enabled = False
    cmdEmpData.Enabled = False
    cmdEmployees.Enabled = True
    cmdReset.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

[image]